# Android Wi-Fi connection DNS failures

Tags: wi-fi, dns

My relative's tablet has started having problems on our Wi-Fi network. It will downright refuse to do DNS resolution (not just locally).

Some information about our network:

- Wi-Fi is delivered through a bunch of Netgear Orbi APs that are connected to an Edge-X router, which is connected to the ISP's modem/router.
- We are not running anything exotic like PiHole or local DNS servers.
- I've used Fing on Android to perform tests, mostly ping. Ping works when using IPs but fails when using hostnames.

Some things I've noticed:

- Traffic to IPs still works.
- Pinging the DNS servers works.
- This happens regardless of the DNS server that has been set up on the router (usually 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8).
- Sometimes it is solved by switching from DHCP to Static and specifying a fixed IP + DNS server IP. It might work for a couple of hours, until it starts failing again. Switching back to DHCP sometimes helps, but not always.
- Playing with the Private DNS feature might also help, but not always and never indefinitely.
- The problem only happens on our own Wi-Fi network.
- Her relative's tablet (exactly the same model and generation) never has this problem. In fact, none of our other devices do.
- The problem happens regardless of which Orbi AP the device is connected to.

I haven't tried the following things:

- Factory reset the tablet (I'd like to postpone this step as long as possible)
- Changing the SSID on our Wi-Fi (would also prefer to postpone since it would mean reconfiguring a lot of our devices).

Any input would be greatly appreciated.